# Test Categories no longer generated from Tags

Tags: specflow

We've recently upgraded to v1.7.1, but our @Tags no longer generate the Visual Studio attributes `[Microsoft.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestCategoryAttribute("MyTag")]` necessary for us to use Test Categories successfully.

The @ignore tag still generates an IgnoreAttribute - so SpecFlow parser is till operational. Also the tag value is being added to the TechTalk.SpecFlow.ScenarioInfo value.

Are there any other settings we need to set?

We're using VS2010 SP1 on Win7 Ent.

Rob.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how it happened, but it turned out our entry in app.config had somehow got changed at the same time. What we needed to do was *reset* the following..

Replace:

```
<specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest" />
</specFlow>
```

With:

```
<specFlow>
    <unitTestProvider name="MsTest.2010" />
</specFlow>
```

..and all seems to work fine again.
Rob.